# LibGDx images are not displayed after second time

Tags: java, android, image, opengl-es, libgdx

From some time I have started having following problem. I play the level it loads files through `AssetManager` and it displays images. I finish the level, it unloads the files. When I play again the level, it only displays fort, player, enemies, bullets but it stopped displaying the rest of the images like ground, background, trees etc, instead it shows me white plain color.

However just right now, instead of getting the textures from AssetManager `ground = manager.get("environment/fields_ground.png");` I just changed everything into creating new objects like `ground = new Texture("environment/fields_ground.png");` and it doesn't produce this error. I guess there is something wrong or missing.

[image: Everything is fine]
[image: It doesn't display rest of the images properly]

It actually was just white plain, but when I created ground as a new texture instead of using AssetManager then it happened as on the picture. I don't unload player image, arrows, but I do unload fort, but the problem doesn't seem to affect it. I assume that something is wrong happening with the AssetManager or it fails to properly clear the screen and batch new images. But files are loaded fine, otherwise it would throw errors. It initializes images otherwise there would be errors and it displays images properly for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I had a silly mistake, which I didn't notice, because I have too many classes to look at. The mistake was that I disposed ground, background and other objects. After I finished the level it called method to dispose these things and then I played level again and it loaded something what was disposed. Therefore, it caused this problem.

Problem was:

```
ground.dispose();
background.dispose();
textureEnvironment.dispose();
```

Solution:
Remove these lines of code.